# Bulma burger isn't shown

Tags: javascript, html, navbar, bulma

I have a problem with the Bulma framework. I have a small navbar for desktop and want to add a navbar burger. But it doesn't work. I tried the js script created by Bulma as an example and one from a yt video. Both didn't work. Can somebody Please help me? Down will find the html part and the js script:

js/index.js

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  // Get all "navbar-burger" elements
  const $navbarBurgers = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.navbar-burger'), 0);

  // Add a click event on each of them
  $navbarBurgers.forEach( el => {
    el.addEventListener('click', () => {

      // Get the target from the "data-target" attribute
      const target = el.dataset.target;
      const $target = document.getElementById(target);

      // Toggle the "is-active" class on both the "navbar-burger" and the "navbar-menu"
      el.classList.toggle('is-active');
      $target.classList.toggle('is-active');

    });
  });
});
```

index.html

```
<script src="js/index.js"></script>
<nav class="navbar" role="navigation" aria-label="main navigation">
  <div class="navbar-brand">
      <a class="navbar-item" href="index.html">
        <h1 class="title">10.8</h1>
      </a>
  
      <a role="button" class="navbar-burger" data-target="navMenu" aria-label="menu" aria-expanded="false">
          <span aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span aria-hidden="true"></span>
        </a>
        
        <div class="navbar-menu" id="navMenu">
          <div class="navbar-menu">
              <div class="navbar-start">
                  <a class="navbar-item">
                      Home
                    </a>
                    <div class="navbar-item has-dropdown is-hoverable">
                      <a class="navbar-link">
                        More
                      </a>
              
                      <div class="navbar-dropdown">
                        <a class="navbar-item">
                          About
                        </a>
                        <a class="navbar-item">
                          Jobs
                        </a>
                        <a class="navbar-item">
                          Contact
                        </a>
                        <hr class="navbar-divider">
                        <a class="navbar-item">
                          Report an issue
                        </a>
                      </div>
                    </div>
              </div>
            
              <div class="navbar-end">
                <!-- navbar items -->
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</nav>
```

Well if watched a small video produced from Bulma, tried the code from theire website and watched another video. I also tried to write my own script but it also does'nt work.
I hope sb can help me to fix it cause this must be successfully really quick.

Answer (score 0):

1. You have a div that doesn't close in the right place.
2. There is a div with duplicate className.

Properly closing and removing that div everything works as expected.

[image]

```js
// Get all "navbar-burger" elements
const $navbarBurgers = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.navbar-burger'), 0);

// Add a click event on each of them
$navbarBurgers.forEach(el => {
    el.addEventListener('click', () => {

        // Get the target from the "data-target" attribute
        const target = el.dataset.target;
        const $target = document.getElementById(target);

        // Toggle the "is-active" class on both the "navbar-burger" and the "navbar-menu"
        el.classList.toggle('is-active');
        $target.classList.toggle('is-active');

    });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bulma/0.9.4/css/bulma.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<body>
    <nav class="navbar" role="navigation" aria-label="main navigation">
        <div class="navbar-brand">
            <a class="navbar-item" href="index.html">
                <h1 class="title">10.8</h1>
            </a>

            <a role="button" class="navbar-burger" data-target="navMenu" aria-label="menu" aria-expanded="false">
                <span aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span aria-hidden="true"></span>
            </a>
        </div>

        <div class="navbar-menu" id="navMenu">
            <div class="navbar-start">
                <a class="navbar-item">
                    Home
                </a>
                <div class="navbar-item has-dropdown is-hoverable">
                    <a class="navbar-link">
                        More
                    </a>

                    <div class="navbar-dropdown">
                        <a class="navbar-item">
                            About
                        </a>
                        <a class="navbar-item">
                            Jobs
                        </a>
                        <a class="navbar-item">
                            Contact
                        </a>
                        <hr class="navbar-divider">
                        <a class="navbar-item">
                            Report an issue
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="navbar-end">
                <!-- navbar items -->
            </div>
        </div>

    </nav>
</body>
```